# Step into not working, but can force stepping after some asm steps

Tags: c++, visual-studio, openssl

In a program I've written I would like to step into an OpenSSL function:
[image: About to try and step into the function]
If I press <kbd>F11</kbd> the program will not step into the function.

However I can step via the disassembly window:
[image]
From here I can step to the `X509_NAME_oneline` call:
[image]
Then, after stepping through a couple of jumps, I can step through the function:
[image]
Next, I can right-click and go to the source code:
[image]
Finally I can go back to stepping through the function in the usual way:
[image]

---

How could I get Visual Studio to step directly into the function in the first place?

Comment: Do you have OpenSSL (_libeay32_) compiled with debug symbols?

Comment: @CristiFati Yes, compiled with debug symbols. I used `perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A`

Comment: Are the debug symbols accessible (and loaded) by _VStudio_, when you run your app? (if yes the _OpenSSL_ pdb files should be mentioned in the _Output_ window).

Comment: @CristiFati Yes, in the modules window I have: `libeay32.dll <install path>\bin\libeay32.dll N/A N/A Symbols loaded. <source tree path>\out32dll\libeay32.pdb 12 1.00.2.8 5/23/2016 4:32 PM 00007FFF968F0000-00007FFF96AF6000 [22152] client.exe` It is also mentioned in the *Output window*.

Comment: Hmm, and the _OpenSSL_ source files are located exactly where they were when you compiled _libeay32_? Because (if I remember correctly) the pdb file contains full paths to source files (at compile/link time).

Comment: @CristiFati Aha! You might be onto something. I have a debug bulid and a regular build. It might be looking at the install path for the release build. I'm checking to confirm now...

Comment: @CristiFati Sadly, no. That wasn't the problem. Even double checking for the paths it does not step into the function.

Comment: @flatmouse - *`perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A`* - that does not provide a debug build *per se*. Also see [Compilation and Installation | Debug Configuration](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Debug_Configuration) in the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww Thanks for the link to the wiki and the many other OpenSSL contributions. The build seems to work well for debugging. How else could I complete a debug build other than with the the `debug-VC-WIN64A` target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the application using the library, the solution was to ensure that the linker is optimizing for debugging and not for faster linking:
[image]

It was previously set to the new default which is [`/Debug:FASTLINK`](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/10/16/debug-fastlink-for-vs2015-update-1.aspx)

---

The library was built from a regular command prompt on Windows 10 with VS 2015 with the following commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
perl Configure debug-VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\Path\to\target\folder
ms\do_win64a
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
cd out32dll.dbg
..\ms\test
cd ..
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak install
```